# Multiple URL for one Drupal 8 website configuration

Tags: 8, uri

I want create one Drupal 8 website (one database) with changing contents depending of the URL the user used, I mean:

- If the user goes to the main URL `http://foo.com`, the main page of the website is loaded and contains some content generated for the `http://foo.com` URL
- If the user goes to the main URL `http://faa.com`, the main page of the website is loaded and contains some content generated for the `http://faa.com` URL

I can manage that with Apache settings. But how can I configure Drupal? If a user uses the URL `http://foo.com` and then, he goes to the subpage `/test`, the URL must become `http://foo.com/test`.
But, if a user goes to the site with the URL `http://faa.com` and then, he goes to the subpage `/test`, I want the base URL still `http://faa.com` (`http://faa.com/test`).

Answer (score 2):

I've handled this situation very easily by setting two different Apache VirtualHost with the same DocumentRoot.

The thing you have to be very careful is the page caching of Drupal. I recommend you to read the [Cache Context](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/cache-api/cache-contexts) document on Drupal 8 who is very helpful for your situation. By passing the "url" cache context on your different render arrays, you will prevent the content of a URL to be displayed on the other.

Drupal routing system doesn't take the domain name. So there'll be no problem and a user who go on a subpage from a domain name will stay on this domain name.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a perfect job for the [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) module.